# titanium content assist is not working for my simple app

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

This is myFirstApp in titanium but its not showing me content Assist 
So please give me right suggestion so i can work with better in titanium.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not selected yet Titanium SDk which is

If you right click on a project, select "Properties" and then "Project Build Path," what SDK file is selected there?

**[description : refer here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/127516/content-assist-not-working-after-latest-update-of-ti-studio-on-mac-os-x#comment-196031)**

Comment: If you have any comments, add it as comment not as answer

Answer (score 0):

well, open tiapp.xml and make sure you select an SDK.

but I can tell from from my experience with Titanium Studion - intelisense doesn't always work. happens to me too. don't really know why.