# android emulator is running but app is not launching in titanium

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium

I am using windows 7 and I have created one basic app that is firstapp i am running this in android emulator it is not launching in emulator.

This app is working fine in android device and webbrowser but its not launching in emulator please give some best hint

and this is my log

[image: Log for running app]

please tell me some need full help

And share me some best tutorials for beginners as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with [this site](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start).
And if you're using Alloy Framework for MVC then follow [this](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework).

Comment: Hey @Khushi shah e to mane pan khabr i have so mane side for learning android,
I want to learn titanium tutorials....
samji gaya...

Comment: ok. so you should go with docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start
And if you're using Alloy Framework for MVC then go with http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework

Comment: I need another help if you can..
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344549/titanium-content-assist-is-not-working-for-my-simple-app

Comment: Actually it happens usually. And don't know why.:(

Comment: I got this problem 

changed in property of project > titanium SDK version..

And how to chat with user in stackoverflow......?????

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42560/discussion-between-scientist-and-khushi-shah)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access a web service/web site from the android device which is on a PC right?
if so please note that when referring to the host machine in the emulator use the ip adress as 10.0.2.2